# How to show a modal-type popup panel directly from C# (not from a UI button-click)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are numerous you-tube videos on how to open a panel from a button-click in Unity.  I would like to know how to show/hide a panel directly from C#.
I've tried:

```
        PromotionPanel panel = new PromotionPanel();
        panel.Show()
```

This seemed reasonable to me... after all that is how I would have done it in the olden days.  But of course I had to fill the Show() method:

```
public void Show()
{
    Panel.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
    canvasGroup.interactable = true;
    canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
}
```

I've also tried other methods...
Like using an 'instance':

```
public class PromotionPanel : MonoBehaviour
{
      public static PromotionPanel Instance { get; private set; }
```

and

```
            PromotionPanel.Instance.Show();
            p2 = PromotionPanel.Instance.promotion;
```

Here I was actually copying another method already used in the same bit of code, used by a previous coder.  However, something was not working... I kept getting a null references. I made sure that everything was setup correctly.  At least I thought so in 'Unity'.

Here is an image of: [image: Unity references]

Comment: Hard to tell for sure but you shouldn't use `new` to instantiate prefabs. Use `Instantiate`. [See here for more information](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)

Comment: hmm... I copied your link in practice: Instantiate(Panel, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); in the PromotionPanel-->Start just as a test.  That caused Unity to crash.  Ideally I need to Instantiate in my promotePiece() code when Its acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm calling it this way:

```
GameManagerStatic.promotion.Show();
```

and inside promotionPanel.cs:

```
public static class GameManagerStatic
{
     public static PromotionPanel promotion;
}
```

and also:

```
  public class PromotionPanel : MonoBehaviour
  {
    [SerializeField] CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
    public GameObject Panel;

    void Start()
    { //assign the static to itself
        GameManagerStatic.promotion = this;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
        canvasGroup.interactable = true;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }
```

I also have a Hide()...